# How can I select only the child divs of a div (and not "grandchildren" divs and so on)?

Tags: html, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, selector

I have a recursive function that creates divs inside divs on demand by the user, but I've stumbled on a problem where I need to separate those divs as in a specific manner, similar to "layers". 
Example: 
I have created a div, firstborn - and inside it, the user created another div (lets call this one child div). Inside this secondary div, the user created yet another div (and this one grandchild div) - I need to know the number of child divs of the firstborn div, and the number of child divs that the child div has (grandchild divs)

I've stumbled upon this issue because the way I was trying to get them was by:

```html
numberOfFirstbornDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("firstBornDiv").length
numberOfChildrenDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("recursivelyCreatedDiv")[index].getElementsByClassName("recursivelyCreatedDiv").length
```

What I wanted was the number of divs named "recursivelyCreatedDiv" only under the first "layer", but instead, I get the number of divs from all subsequent "layers" (in the given example I wanted to have:
numberOfFirstbornDivs = 1 and 
numberOfChildrenDivs = 1, 
but instead I get:
numberOfFirstbornDivs = 1 and 
numberOfChildrenDivs = 2).

I understand this happens because I name my divs by the same ClassName, but I don't know how to workaround this as they are created recursively (and on demand by the user).

Answer (score 1):

To only select direct childs of an element you can use the '>' css selector instead of getting elements by class name.

For example, .firstBornDiv > .recursivelyCreatedDiv will target all elements with the recursivelyCreatedDiv class that are direct children of a div with the firstBornDiv class

Edit 1: To be more precise, you can use the  querySelectorAll() method with any css selector to get the array of elements targeted by your selector which is what you would need with this answer.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was in need of.

Comment: Edit: This didn't work, but sure did like it did lol
unfortunatelly it did not solve my problem.